# Return aggregated array from input multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, aggregate

I've got two inputs, an ID and multidimensional array

For example, let's say the ID = 5 and the array looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [year] => 2017
            [value] => a:9:{i:5;b:1;i:38;b:1;i:40;b:1;i:42;b:1;i:44;b:1;i:29;b:1;i:46;b:1;i:27;b:1;i:48;b:1;}
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [year] => 2018
            [value] => a:9:{i:31;b:1;i:5;b:1;i:25;b:1;i:16;b:1;i:27;b:1;i:29;b:1;i:12;b:1;i:14;b:1;i:34;b:1;}
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [year] => 2018
            [value] => a:3:{i:12;b:1;i:14;b:1;i:16;b:1;}
        )

)
```

I need to unserialize the value and aggregate the data yearly. For example of ID = 5, the output should look like this:

```
Array
(
    [2017] => 1
    [2018] => 1
)
```

Currently I've got so far as to unserialize the value part:

```
foreach($results as $object=>$result){
    echo $result->year;
    echo "<br>";
    echo join(',', array_keys(unserialize($result->value)));    
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Please advise on how to move on from here.

Comment: Not sure if your output is clear - do you want the contents of element 5 of the unserialized array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you unserialize the value, check if the element whose key is ID is set. If it is, increment a counter for the year.

```
$id = 5;
$output = array();
foreach ($results as $result) {
    $value = unserialize($result->value);
    if (!empty($value[$id])) {
        if (isset($output[$result->year])) {
            $output[$result->year]++;
        } else {
            $output[$result->year] = 1;
        }
    }
}
print_r($output);
```